# Restricción de bucle en un archivo csv sin usar pandas

Tags: python

Estoy leyendo dos archivos y guardando del archivo `ar1` en un diccionario las columnas 2 y 4.

Quiero hacer un loop para los valores de los archivos, pero me salen los valores en blanco. Me pasa lo mismo utilizando *list slicing*.

Ya probé el fichero csv y si tiene datos, al parecer solo me permite hacer un solo loop dentro de `with open()`, porque cuando hago ese loop aparte si me corrió.

¿Alguna ayuda o sugerencia?

```py
with open(csv1, 'r') as ar1, open(csv2, 'r') as ar2:
    leer_1 = csv.reader(ar1, delimiter = ',', quotechar = " ")
    leer_2 = csv.reader(ar2, delimiter = ',', quotechar = " ")
    #lista_prueba = [u[4] for u in leer_1]
    ejemplo = {x[4]: {u[2] for u in leer_1 if u[4] == x[4]} for x in leer_1}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir a tu pregunta un ejemplo de como son los archivos csv? Has probado usar `csv.DictReader` para que cargue cada línea del archivo en un diccionario en vez de `csv.reader` quizás eso podría evitar que necesites hacer un bucle con `for` para obtener el diccionario

Comment: Estás usando el iterador `leer_1` dos veces. Al estar anidado, este iterador se "agota" en el bucle interno, con lo que el bucle externo sólo llega a ver la primera línea, por eso te sale vacío. No veo claro cómo quieres comparar un fichero con otro, pero si lo explicas, con ejemplo de las entradas y los resultados, igual te podemos dar un código que funcione.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte